# How to extract html tag name from std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, substring, stdstring

In this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <sstream>


struct tag {
    bool isOpening;
    std::string name;
};

void print(const std::deque<tag> &deq){
    for(const auto &i : deq){
        std::cout << i.name << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
//    std::ifstream infile("a.html");
//    std::stringstream buffer;
//    buffer << infile.rdbuf();
//    std::string buf = std::move(buffer.str());
    std::deque<tag> deq;
    std::string buf = "<html>\n"
                      "\n"
                      "<body>\n"
                      "    <h1>Hello <b>world</b></h1>\n"
                      "</body>\n"
                      "\n"
                      "</html>";

    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = buf.find('<', pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        bool isOpening = true;
        if(buf[pos+1] == '/'){
            isOpening = false;
            pos++;
        }
        std::string token = buf.substr(pos, buf.find('>', pos));
        deq.push_back({isOpening, token});
        pos++;
    }

    print(deq);
}
```

I would like to parse for each tag its name and whether it is opening or not. But the output is:

```
<html
<body>
    <h
<h1>Hello <b>world</b>
<b>world</b></h1>
</body>

</ht
/b></h1>
</body>

</html>
/h1>
</body>

</html>
/body>

</html>
/html>
```

which is of course not correct. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

the `substr` function in c++ takes in two arguments: The position, and the *length* of the substring, and not the start and end positions. So you're basically having almost all of the substrings be for the entire string, which is why you see so much repeated output. You're really just wanting to take that `substr` command and change it to

```
 buf.substr(pos, buf.find('>', pos)-pos-1);
```

Hope that works!